# Quicksort isn't working faster when I pick a pivot such as median or mode

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm having a problem as I test my Quicksort implementation. I was told that the algorithm will work better when we pick a number such as the median as pivot, however, my results aren't what I expected. Usually, the best case-scenario is happening when I pick either the first or the last element as pivot, and both of them are random numbers just like all the other elements in the array. I'm running lots of tests (over 5000) and checking the average time (without the time to look for the mode or median). Thank you.

Comment: It's easier to debug code when you can see the code.

Comment: Then [comb sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort) was used. And everyone rejoiced.

Comment: Why exactly do you think picking the mode would make quicksort faster? o.o If the mode is the same as the min or the max, it could seriously slow down quicksort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the median or mode of the array is an expensive operation (especially picking the median), so even though you'll get good pivots the additional overhead of finding those pivots will probably eat up most of your efficiency gains.

Randomized quicksort (where you pick a random pivot each time) ends up being a much better choice in practice. Its worst-cases are exponentially unlikely and on expectation it runs in time O(n log n). It's also way faster to generate a random or pseudorandom number than it is to find the median or mode of an array.

Finally, if you do choose the *mode* of an array, there's no guarantee at all that you get a good pivot. In fact, this can lead to pathological cases if you have an array with no duplicates and your implementation of picking the mode always chooses the min or max value. That will degenerate to Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not adding the time I take to find the mode or median. But thank you anyway